# Can I run a docker container from the browser?

Tags: docker, browser, docker-compose

I don't suppose anyone knows if it's possible to call the `docker run` or `docker compose up` commands from a web app?

I have the following scenario in which I have a react app that uses openlayers for it's maps. I have it so that when the user loses internet connection it fallback onto making the requests to a [map server](https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server) running locally on docker. The issue is that the user needs to manually start the server via the command line. To make things easier for the user, I added the following bash script and docker compose file to boot up the server with a single command, but was wondering if I could incorporate that functionality into the web app and have the user boot the map server by the click of a button?

Just for references sake these are my bash and compose files.

```
#!/bin/sh

dockerDown=`docker info | grep -qi "ERROR" && echo "stopped"`

if [ $dockerDown ]
then
  echo "\n ********* Please start docker before running this script ********* \n"
  exit 1
fi

skipInstall="no"
read -p "Have you imported the maps already and just want to run the app (y/n)?" choice
case "$choice" in
  y|Y ) skipInstall="yes";;
  n|N ) skipInstall="no";;
  * ) skipInstall="no";;
esac

pbfUrl='https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/malaysia-singapore-brunei-latest.osm.pbf'
#polyUrl='https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/malaysia-singapore-brunei.poly'
#-e DOWNLOAD_POLY=$polyUrl \

docker volume create openstreetmap-data
docker volume create openstreetmap-rendered-tiles

if [ $skipInstall = "no" ]
then
  echo "\n ***** IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME, YOU MIGHT WANT TO GO GET A CUP OF COFFEE WHILE YOU WAIT ***** \n"
  docker run \
      -e DOWNLOAD_PBF=$pbfUrl \
      -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main \
      -v openstreetmap-rendered-tiles:/var/lib/mod_tile \
      overv/openstreetmap-tile-server \
      import

  echo "Finished Postgres container!"
fi

echo "\n *** BOOTING UP SERVER CONTAINER *** \n"

docker compose up
```

My docker compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  map:
    image: overv/openstreetmap-tile-server
    volumes:
      - openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main
      - openstreetmap-rendered-tiles:/var/lib/mod_tile
    environment:
      - THREADS=24
      - OSM2PGSQL_EXTRA_ARGS=-C 4096
      - AUTOVACUUM=off
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    command: "run"

volumes:
  openstreetmap-data:
    external: true
  openstreetmap-rendered-tiles:
    external: true
```

Comment: From a web site, you want the ability to execute scripts on the client's machine? That seems like it would be a very useful feature for attackers.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Docker API, and you are able to start containers,

In the Docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/

To start the containers using the Docker API
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerStart

Comment: Looked into it and there is no reference for running or starting container from the browser in their docs. Makes sense given this could be a massive security issue.

Comment: The following link is from the Docker's documentation on how to start a container using the Docker API, https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerStart